# mySQL vs XML vs plain text file speed and efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, xml, csv

I want to know what would be the most efficient and thus, the fastest way to store and check a "new order flag" (NOF)

The purpose is to avoid overhead for an online food ordering system for a pizza franchise.

In the back end, every 3+/- minutes an AJAX function will check the NOF  If it is true/1/yes, it will query the database and get all the current orders for the store.  If there are no orders it will just reset the timer and check again in 3+/- minutes.

When an order is placed, it is inserted into the db, and the NOF will be updated for the appropriate store.

there are about 15 separate stores. I also need to be storing the timestamp each time the check is done.

I can store the timestamp and NOF in the same var as an 11 char. string, the first 10 being the time stamp, and the last a T/F or Y/N or 1/0

So what would be the best way of storing/checking the NOF/timestamp?

Thanks

Comment: "in the same var" - bad choice. ALWAYS use native types when storing in the db, never a "compound" field. use a timestamp/datetime field and a bit field for your two values. The point of a relational DB is to be able to RELATE data. if you stuff multiple independent bits of data into a field, you remove the ability of the db to do that relational stuff automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're making this way too complex. If the table has a field for the time an order was created (e.g. tcreated) and another for the time it was completed (tcomp, defaults to NULL), then your query every 3 minutes just checks the for the rows 'WHERE tcomp IS NULL.

Comment: As suggested, I could just query the whole table of orders, filter out only the ones for a single store, and then check all those orders for NULL in the "timeRecived" column, but that seems like more work then testing for a single bool response from either 1 table column on 1 row, or a single file.  I guess what I want to know is how to most efficiently (with the least resources, and fastest) check for new orders?